# proof 0 (f (n)) = 0 (g(n)) if and only if f (n) E 0 (g(n)) and g(n) E O (f (n))

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, data-structure

The problem :

```
For arbitrary functions f and g : IN -> IR*, prove that
```

1. O(f (n)) = O(g(n)) if and only if  
   f
   (
   n
   )
   ∈
   O
   (
   g
   (
   n
   )
   )
     and 
   g
   (
   n
   )
   ∈
   O
   (
   f
   (
   n
   )
   )
   .

I tried to do it by definition :

So given
  f
  (
  n
  )
  ∈
  O
  (
  g
  (
  n
  )
  ) and   g
  (
  n
  )
  ∈
  O
  (
  f
  (
  n
  )
  )
.

```
 ∃ C1>0 ,∃ n1>0 so that for all n> n1 , f(n) ≤ C1*g(n).

 and

 ∃ C2>0 , ∃ n2>0 so that for all n> n2 , g(n) ≤ C2*f(n).

 so for n'=max(n1,n2) => f(n) ≤ C1*g(n) and g(n) ≤ C2*f(n)
```

but i don't understand how to continue,i tried to start from the other side but without success.

How can this claim be proven by definition?

Comment: [mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit this.